# Submaximality of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

A topological space (X,T) is said to be submaximal if every dense subset of X is open. I also noticed another definition saying that X is submaximal if it is the intersection of an open subset and a closed subset. My doubt is that whether this two definitions are equivalent. If yes kindly post the proof.

Answer (score 1):

A [google search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_topology) told me that submaximality of $X$ is equivalent to the property that every subset of $X$ is locally closed, i.e., an intersection of an open subset and a closed subset.

Assume that $X$ is submaximal, then every dense subset is open. For every subset $S \subset X$ we know that $O=X\setminus (\overline{S} \setminus S )$ is dense in $X$, since taking closures preserves inclusions. By assumtion $O$ is open and $S= O\cap \overline{S}$. Thus $S$ is locally closed.

Conversely assume that every subset of $X$ is locally closed if $D$ is dense then is is the intersection of an open set $O$ and a closed set $C$. But we have $X = \overline{O\cap C} \subset \overline{O} \cap \overline{C} $ but since $\overline C = C$ we know that $C=X$ and thus $O=D$. Hence $D$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Your second "definition" is very strange !

We have $X= X \cap X$. Since $X$ is open and closed, every topological space is submaximal, according your second "definition".

Comment: Perhaps what is meant is that $X\subset Y$ is submaximal when $X=A\cap B$ with $A,B$ open/closed in $Y$. However even this does not make sense since $[0,1]\cap(0,1)=(0,1)$ is not submaximal in the first sense.